# Basic programming class...first time using a string.

Tags: java

I am supposed to make a program that incorporates methods and a string format. The situation is that the user inputs a new Tree example: Tree t = new Tree(27, 43.25, "Pine") and then type t.describe() and receive this output 
"Tree number 27 has a circumference of 43.25 and is of species Pine."

Here is my code:

```
public class Tree{

  int serial;
  double circumference;
  String species;


  Tree(int serial, double circumference, String species) {

    this.serial = serial;
    this.circumference = circumference;
    this.species = species; 
  }
  public String describe() {
    String.format("Tree number %d has a circumference of %.2f and is of species %s.", serial, circumference, species);

    return describe();
  }
}
```

The program just blows up though. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you me by "The program just blows up though."

Comment: This will cause a stackoverflowexception :)

Comment: For future questions that are producing exceptions, please paste the entire stack trace into your question; it makes identifying more complex problems much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `describe()` within `describe()`, with nothing stopping it from calling itself ad infinitum.  You must be getting a `StackOverflowError`.

The solution here is simple - `String.format` returns the `String` you want.  Just return it.

```
return String.format("Tree number %d has a circumference of %.2f and is of species %s.",
    serial, circumference, species);
```

Also, do not call `describe()` from with `describe()`.  That's what made it "blow up".